# Assign any unique identifier to elements in a inflated view

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I wanted to know if we can assign any unique number to elements inside an inflated view.

My view looks like this and this image might give you an idea what I'm trying to do:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is I'm changing the values of the edit text boxes based on the spinner item selected like this:

```
//spinnerPlanItinerary is the first spinner
    spinnerPlanItinerary.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                List<Town> listOfTowns = new ArrayList<Town>();
                ArrayAdapter<Town> townplanitineraryadapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<Town>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, listOfTowns);
                townplanitineraryadapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinnerTown.setAdapter(townplanitineraryadapter2);
                spinnerTown.setText(""); //second spinner in the view
                edBelt.setText(""); //first edit text in the view
                edStrata.setText(""); //second edit text in the view

                townplanitineraryadapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

I can't give any unique IDs to the element since they already have IDs in my layout file. I've also been using `setTag()` and `getTag()` but `getTag()` doesnt give me anything.

Also note that the card views are inflated onclick of a button like this:

```
final LinearLayout itineraryDetailLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.itineraryDetailLinearlayout);

        final View childView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);
        itineraryDetailLL.addView(childView);
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you try to do? The IDs from the layout file **are** already unique IDs. Why need a second and for what? You have everything you need... You react on the click and then you set values to your text fields.

Comment: @Grisgram, The edit text on both the inflated views has the same id since the same view is inflated twice as you can see the image. My problem is whenever I select a different item from the first spinner in the first inflated view the changes (setting the values in edit texts) occur in the second inflated view elements. I hope this has made my question clear.

Comment: @Grisgram, I've edited my question a bit too.

Comment: You can set a unique id by calling `setTag(Object object)`

Comment: ah I see - you add them dynamically - ok now I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for clarifying in the comments.

From what I understand now is, that you dynamically inflate and add additional text fields. Then they all have the same ID, correct.

So, how can you distinguish them then?
Easy solution:

```
final View childView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);
itineraryDetailLL.addView(childView);
```

You should not make only one `childView` member, but create a list of them (or Dictionary, or whatever fits best for your next actions).
In **each** of them you can do a `.findViewById` for the ID of the edit-text contained in that view.

So, maybe it could look like this:

```
Map<Integer, View> myChilds = new ....
final View childView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardview, null);
itineraryDetailLL.addView(childView);
// Here is your "make it unique" part:
myChilds.put(your_next_unique_id, childView);
...
// When you want to access them
EditText txt = myChilds.get(my_unique_id).findViewById(xml_id_of_edittext);
txt.setText("...");
```

I hope you get the idea where this can lead you to.
Cheers, Gris

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try

Comment: This is solution is Lit! Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the value of the EditText you do not need to a unique identifier for that. You can do this:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("someSpinnerData")) {
                  editText.setText("yourDesiredText");    
        } else if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("someSpinnerData2")) {
                  editText.setText("someSpinnerData2");    
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```